# Laravel - Radom Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I have read some posts about this topic but can't find how to fix it.
I reviewed apache logs and there are not errors there.
This error can appear whenever I'm using the application or also when I execute `php artisan serve` without loading any file.

Do you know where do I can start looking at?

My Devlopment configuration is:

- Laragon Full Edition: Apache 2.4, Nginx, MySQL 5.7, PHP 7.2

[image]

Regards

Comment: Seems like server configuration error. Try to update composer and then update your project and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks @HassaanAli I will try it and let you know. Regards